# BigQuery data using SQL "INSERT INTO" is gone after some time

Tags: google-bigquery

Today I notice another strange behaviour of BigQuery. 
I run UDF standard SQL in the BQ web ui:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION ...
INSERT INTO projectid.dataset.inserttable...
```

All seems good, the result of the UDF SQL are inserted in the insert table correct, I can tell from "Number of rows". But the table size is not correct, still keep the table size before run the insert query. Furthermore, I found all the inserted rows are gone after 1 hour later.

Some more info I found, when run a "DETELE FROM insert table true" or "SELECT ...", then the deleted number of rows and table size seems correct with the inserted data. But just can not preview the insert table correctly in the WEB UI.

Then I am guessing the "Detail" or "Preview" info of the table has time delay? May I know do you have any idea about this behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The preview may have a delay, so `SELECT * FROM YourTable;` will give the most up-to-date results, or you can use `COUNT(*)` just to verify that the number of rows is correct. You can think of it as being similar to streaming, if you have tried that, where some rows may be in the streaming buffer for a while before they make it into regular storage.

Comment: thanks for the reply. But why the number of rows first seems correct, and I can also preview the table in web ui, but the data then is gone in about 1 hour? Is that related the data stable in BQ? The issue happens even when the data to be inserted is only 100 rows.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean--is the data gone from the table (if you do a `SELECT * ...`) or is it gone from the preview? The data inserted is always stable. If the insert succeeds, you can run another query immediately afterward and see the latest data.

Comment: no, the data is not gone from the table, I can run "delete" and "select" correctly. The data is "gone" from the "Detail" and "Preview" when checking in the web ui. I say it is gone, because the data does showed correct info in "Detail" and "Preview" just after run the "insert into" query, but then the rows are deducted after some time. That is why it is strange to me. I later also found that the "Table size" and "Last Modified" alway not updated when run the "INSERT INTO" query.

Comment: You cannot rely on the preview for the table being up to date. As I mentioned in the answer, it's similar to streaming, where it takes some time before the modification is committed, so you need to run a query to see the most recent data.

Comment: thanks for your patient explanation. Yes, I understand it has delay to commit.  My point is: if it has delay, then it should not show the correct rows in "Detail" and "Preview" at first, right? The "Detail" and "Preview" show correct rows just after run the "insert into", but then the number is changed to the row number before the "insert into". That is something strange to me. OK, let us say all above is normally performance when running BQ. And may I know normally how long will it take the modification to be committed and display correctly in the preview? Thanks

Comment: It's hard to say how long it might take for the preview to update, unfortunately. There aren't any explicit guarantees.

Comment: OK, got it, thanks very much, will keep this in mind.